# How to extract the creation date of _id and add it as a new field using the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying for a while to extract the insertion date of a mongodb document and add it as a new field to the same document.

I'm trying to do it using the mongo and mongo shell aggregation framework without getting good results.

Here is my query

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate(
   [    
      {
         $match: {
            MY QUERY CRITERIA
          }
      },
      { 
         $addFields: { "insertTime": "$_id.getTimestamp()" } 
      }
   ]
)
```

I am trying to extracr insertion time from _id using the function `getTimestamp()` but for sure there is somtehing about aggregation framework syntax that I am missing because I can not do what I am trying  to do in my query.

This works perfect:

```
ObjectId("5c34f746ccb26800019edd53").getTimestamp()

ISODate("2019-01-08T19:17:26Z")
```

But this does not work at all:

```
"$_id.getTimestamp()"
```

**What I am missing?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `{$addFields: { "insertTime": {"$toDate":"$_id" }}}` from 4.0 version

Comment: Your examples that work are using JavaScript functions in the `mongo` shell (client-side evaluation). The aggregation framework runs on the MongoDB server and does not support JavaScript. You need to use [aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) available in your version of MongoDB server, which would be [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in MongoDB 4.0 as already mentioned. For earlier server versions you would have to fetch the document and add the field in your client code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I will try updating my MongoDB server and use the operator $toDate.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `$addFields` with `"$_id"`:

```js
{
    $addFields: {
        date: {"$toDate": "$_id"}
    }
}
```